# Rails thin stop using pid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I have a Rails Thin server running on my iMac.  Normally, I ctl-c to stop it.  But, my terminal windows got closed and now I'm trying to stop Thin.

I tried this:

```
$ thin stop
```

And got this:

```
no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.pid
```

But, the PID is tmp/pids/server.pid

I've tried this:

```
$ thin stop -C tmp/pids/server.pid
```

But, I get this:

```
undefined method `each' for 8395:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just look for the current Thin pid:

```
cat tmp/pids/server.pid
```

It will give you the current pid like for instance 6458.
Then just issue a:

```
kill -9 6458
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: `kill -9 thin_pid`

Answer (score 0):

`-C` is the parameter for the config file, use `-P` (that is capital p) instead.

```
thin stop -P tmp/pids/server.pid
```

The thing is, when you start rails with thin as its webserver, e.g.:

```
rails server
```

it creates the file **tmp/pids/server.pid**, not the thin default **tmp/pids/thin.pid**, that is why you have to specify the correct pid file.